# Call node from powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell, github-actions, terser

I am trying to create a yml file for a Github locally hosted action runner that calls an npm module called "terser" to minify js and css.

```
  - name: Minify_JS
  if:  ${{ contains(inputs.SHOULD_MINIFY, 'true') }}
  run: | 
      $folder = "C:\Build\${{inputs.REPOS_NAME}}"
      $files = get-childitem $folder -recurse -force -include *.js    
      foreach($file in $files){ D:\Progra~1\nodejs\node.exe C:\Build\node_modules\terser\bin\terser --compress --mangle --output $file.FullName -- $file.FullName    }
      echo "JS minified!"
      #java -jar  D:\Atlassian\Bamboo-Ant-Tasks\lib\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar $file.FullName -o $file.FullName
```

So the operative line of code is `D:\Progra~1\nodejs\node.exe C:\Build\node_modules\terser\bin\terser --compress --mangle --output $file.FullName -- $file.FullName`

That line will work from the command line but when I run it via the action runner I get the error below.

```
D:\Progra~1\nodejs\node.exe : The term 'D:\Progra~1\nodejs\node.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
```

function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\actions-runner_work_temp\beb4cf2f-8512-429c-8624-a9493ed16748.ps1:4 char:27

- foreach($file in $files){ D:\Progra~1\nodejs\node.exe C:\Build\node_m ...
- ```
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Progra~1\nodejs\node.exe:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExcept
    ion
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Use `& D:\Progra~1\nodejs\node.exe` instead of `D:\Progra~1\nodejs\node.exe`.

Comment: @LexLi, given that the executable path is neither quoted nor contains variable references, invocation via `&` cannot be expected to make a difference.

Comment: Generally speaking: Avoid short (8.3) file paths, as they are _machine-specific_. If using a non-shortened path requires it to be _quoted_ (due to containing, e.g., _spaces_), invoke it via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-). Preferably, make sure that the target executable is in one of the directories listed in `$env:PATH`, which allows you to invoke it by _name_ only (e.g. `node.exe`).

Comment: If the executable is not in a directory listed in `$Env:Path`, do not use an 8.3 path. Use `$Env:ProgramFiles\nodejs\node.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that "Environment variables are not hot reloaded so every time new commands get added to the path, power shell, cmd or the GitHub service need to be restarted so they can load the new environment..."  so in our case we just restarted the Github Action Runner Service that gets installed on windows and that fixed the issue